# Swift - Correct way to set APNSToken Firebase Messaging

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im working with Firebase notification for the first time in iOS.

This is my code now:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/ios")
    Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/general")
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

    print("Registration succeeded!")
}
```

Its working like a charm in development.

But my question is: **is this the correct way to do it?**

and, the way it is now, will still work in **production**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created a develop Target you can separate them like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    #if DEVELOPMENT
        //Develop
        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: .sandbox)
    #else
        //Production
        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: .prod)
    #endif
}
```